# ActionMailer sends emails even though it failed with ArgumentError: A sender required to send a message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, delayed-job

Looks like my emails raising errors *and* sending.

I'm receiving emails and also I get this error on "rake jobs:work" console:

> Class#deliver_and_save failed with ArgumentError: A sender (Return-Path, Sender or From) required to send a message - 1 failed attempts

But when I step through my debugger, I can see that there *is* a `from`:

```
> email.from
=> ["my@email.com"]
> email_draft.From
=> Me <my@email.com>
> email_draft.sender
=> nil
> email_draft.Sender
=> nil
> email_draft.reply_to
=> ["my@email.com"]
```

Is it possible that ActionMailer is throwing the error and still sending? Is this a known issue? The problem I have is that delayed_job keeps sending the email repeatedly.

**UPDATE:**

```
def EmailEngine < ActionMailer::Base

  # Called with EmailEngine.delay.deliver_and_save(template)
  def deliver_and_save(template)

    # This appears to be raising the error
    email_draft = EmailEngine.send(template) # this will invoke 'mail'

    # Saved here to have a better record than the logs provide
    Email.create(...

    # Yet this still sends
    email_draft.deliver
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem!

[delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) doesn't play super well with rails 3.1 and you have to use this new syntax:

```
EmailEngine.delay.deliver_and_save(template) # I was already doing this.
```

which it *automatically* tries to calls `.deliver` on the Mail::Message object that `deliver_and_save` returns. (So there's my problem: trying to call `.deliver` myself.)

**SOLUTION:** I rearranged my code and to call `Email.create(..` somewhere outside of `EmailEngine` and then I called `EmailEngine.delay.send(template)` directly and completely removed `deliver_and_save`.

Woo!

Btw, **any method invoked on a class that inherits from ActionMailer will return a Mail::Message object**. ActionMailer does some black magic to make this happen (overwriting Ruby's `method_missing` so it can render views just like a controller, even though it behaves like a model in many ways).

Comment: By the way, I found a workaround as well: just invoke delayed_job's 'delay' method on a class that does *not* inherit from ActionMailer, and then call your ActionMailer method from there. It's like calling delay on ActionMailer through a proxy method and that works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is about delayed_job and rails-3-mailer: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#rails-3-mailers